# Trigger an event created by .on()

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I have a jQuery event defined as follows :

```
$('#pagebody').on('click', '#serverCompTab', function () {
    toggleTabs('#serverComp', '#serverCompTab');
});
```

I would like to trigger this event manually on my code like `$('#'serverCompTab].onclick();`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you just not call toggleTabs('#serverComp', '#serverCompTab'); ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `click()` instead of `onclick()` :

```
$('#serverCompTab').click();
//Or
$('#serverCompTab').trigger('click');
```

**NOTE :** you should replace `]` by `)` and move the quote to the end :

```
$('#'serverCompTab]
____^_____________^
    |             |__ //Replace it by ')'
    |__ //Move it to the end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You were really close. `$('#serverCompTab').click()` should take care of it for you.